# memory management in Mathematica

Tags: memory

Unlike using

```
Unprotect[In,Out];
Clear[In,Out];
Protect[In,Out];
```

to clean the occupied memory of the whole notebook, I want to clean the memory dynamically and accurately. That is, I want to clean out the specific memory I assign whenever I need.

For example, I wrote a loop and at each loop, it generates some intermediate results that need not to be stored and I just want to clean its corresponding memory at the end of each loop. How can I achieve it ?

For example,

```
For[i=0,i<=100,i++,
    x=Array[#&,{1000,1000}];(*occupy many memory*)
    Total[x];
    (*after the Total operation, the x is worthless now
      so I want to clean out its memory
      How should I do*)
    ]
```

Comment: Your best bet is to not use stateful code (variables and assignments), if that can be avoided (and in most cases it can) - then the memory will be claimed automatically by garbage collector. If you use mutable variables, localize them (with `Module`, for example, or in some cases `Block`), then those variables will also be cleared automatically at the end (except in a few pathological cases which you are unlikely to hit in practice).

Comment: One thing to remember is that the kernel stores previous results by default in `Out[n]`.  You can control the number of stored results by adjusting `HistoryLength`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Block` for this purpose.
From Mathematica [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html):

> When you execute a block, values assigned to x, y, ... are
>   cleared. When the execution of the block is finished, the original
>   values of these symbols are restored.

For the example you gave, you should use something like:

```
Clear[x]
For[i=0,i<=100,i++,
     totalx = Block[{x},
                        x=Array[#&,{1000,1000}];
                        Total[x]
                    ]
     (*do something with totalX*)
]
```

**Benchmarking**

Using `MemoryInUse[]`, before and after executing the code, testing with an `Array` of `10,000 x 1,000`, I ran the following code:

```
a = 1; (* to make sure the Kernel is up and running *)
memBefore = MemoryInUse[]
  (* ... the For loop ... with Array[#&,{10000,1000}] *)
memAfter = MemoryInUse[]
extraMemUsed = memAfter - memBefore;
N[extraMemUsed/1024/1024] (* in MB *)
```

Starting with a fresh kernel each time, the original code leaves the kernel with extra `78 MB` of memory usage, whereas the code using `Block` leaves the kernel with only `0.2 MB` of extra memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the `Clear` function to a symbol to clear values and definitions for that symbol, e.g.:

```
Clear[x]
```